# Show authors in acl template

Tags: packages, author, package-options

I am working on an ACL paper using the `acl` package: `\usepackage[review]{acl}`. Doing this, the paper shows '*Anonymous ACL submission*' in the author's block. My track is single-blinded so I should show the authors.

To show the names, I noticed I could run `\usepackage[]{acl}`. However, this changes the document more than I want. Is there another way to use the same package and show the authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
\maketitle
```

by

```
{\makeatletter\acl@finalcopytrue
  \maketitle
}
```

`\acl@finalcopytrue` sets the internal switch for the final version. Since the character `@` is not valid in macro names outside of style files, we have to make it a letter first (`\makeatletter`). Finally, to confine the mode switch (as well as the effect of `\makeatletter`) to the title, we put it into a group (`{...}`).